# Bloomberg - Excel // Data Extract// Mortgage backed security// pool factor

Tags: excel, bloomberg, data-extraction

I am trying to extract the pool factor from Bloomberg to MS Excel.

I have the `MBS CUSIP 3138WHXD9`. I want to pull the Sep 2016 pool factor to excel.

I used below formula:

```
=BDH("3138WHXD9 CUSIP","PDI","MTG_HIST_COLLAT_BAL_FACTOR","09/2016")
```

It returns:

## N/A Start Date

Can anyone tell me how to get the pool factor of 09/2016 to excel?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

managed to get the answer

=BDP("3138WHXD9 CUSIP","MTG_FACTOR")

thx

Answer (score 0):

Your formula will give you the latest factor, which currently points to Sept 2016. You can check the date of the latest value, i.e. the value retrieved by your formula, by running

```
=BDP("3138WHXD9 Cusip","MTG_FACTOR_DT")
```

Should you wish to see historical factors, you can run

```
=BDS("3138WHXD9 Cusip","MTG_HIST_FACT")
```

Noting the adjustment from =BDP (Bloomberg Data Point) to =BDS (Bloomberg Data Set).